# R Package RMySQL: Can't convert character to VARCHAR MYSQL without errors

Tags: r

So I'm using the RMySQL package to set up a local MYSQL server. I've set up a table but I'm having trouble with some of the data conversion types. In particular I've converted a date type in R to a string and I'm using the following query to test uploading the data to MYSQL:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES( 2 , 1.356998403e+15, 747, 240, 2012-12-31, 3493, 0, -6.236852, 53.425327, -709, 747006, 40040, 4094, 0 )
```

But when I test the output from the table from MYSQL using:

```
dbGetQuery(mydb,"SELECT * FROM table1;")
```

I'm getting the following output (truncated):

```
TimestampID    Timestamp LineID JourneyPatternID TimeFrame VehicleJourneyID 
2              1.356998e+15 747              240      1969             3493
```

Notice the difference between the 5th column (TimeFrame) in the input and output? "2012-12-31" becomes "1969"! I've tried inputting as a date but the RMySQL command gave me an error about the date type so I tried switching it to just a character just to get the data in there.

Anyone know what's going on here? How can I get the character into VARCHARas it is shown in R?

Here's the table setup:

```
dbSendQuery(mydb, "
  CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  TimestampID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Timestamp BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  LineID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
  JourneyPatternID VARCHAR(8),
  TimeFrame VARCHAR (15),
  VehicleJourneyID INT UNSIGNED,
  Congestion BOOL,
  LonWGS84 NUMERIC(10,8),
  LatWGS84 NUMERIC(10,8),
  Delay INT,
  BlockID INT UNSIGNED,
  VehicleID INT UNSIGNED,
  StopID INT UNSIGNED,
  AtStop BOOL,
  PRIMARY KEY (TimestampID)
  );
")
```

Comment: Hi @Cormac85, welcome to [stats.se]. Unfortunately this is a site for statistics-related questions. Your question would be better suited to the sister site [so]. I have voted to close your question and have it migrated (so you don't need to do anything) to [so].

Comment: My bad. I thought because it was an R related question it would be best suited to the stats side of things. Cheers!

Comment: It looks like `2012-12-31` is being parsed as "2012 minus 12 minus 31", which would explain why you are getting a `1969` in your 5th column. How about using `'2012-12-31'` (with single quotes) instead of `2012-12-31` in your `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Wow thanks, that's exactly it! It's always the stupid errors that get me :(

Answer (score 0):

Just so this actually has an answer..

You need to add quotes around the '2012-12-31' value in your INSERT command.  It should read:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES( 2 , 1.356998403e+15, 747, 240, '2012-12-31', 3493, 0, -6.236852, 53.425327, -709, 747006, 40040, 4094, 0 )
```